# how to pass javascript variables from one javaScript file to another javascript file?

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript files in one folder.I want to pass a variable one javascript file to another.what procedure should I use?

Comment: Your title says 'one page to another', and your question says 'one javascript file to another'. They're very different concepts; which do you mean?

Comment: You are including both on the one page? Please add more detail, at the moment your question is unclear.

Comment: exactly I want to send the variable one javascript file to another javascript file.they are in one folder.

Comment: have a look at the below:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343801/pass-variable-to-external-js-file

Comment: @lakashman And those JavaScript files are executed how? Are they included inside HTML pages which are loaded in a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) is used for cross document messages. Use those messages to share data.

Answer (score 0):

Question is bit confusing, 
If the 2 javascript files are in 2 different pages you can use a query string to pass the values.

If both of them are in a single page the value can be simply passed using a variable. Simply define the variable int he first called script file or in the page. It can be accessed from any other javascript in the page defined below the first script.