# How to access session variable from JavaScript file (.js) file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to access session variable from `javascript` file

I am using below code to access from `javascript`,

```
var sessionValue = '<%=Session["username"]%>'
            alert(sessionValue)
```

it is working well when the script function is placed inside the `aspx page`...but when I use the same code in `.js` file it is not working

I have seen all the related answers, nothing is useful for me, so don't mark it as duplicate

Comment: because `Session` is not available in `.js` file. It can be access from your apsx page only.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343801/pass-variable-to-external-js-file

Comment: @Shahe actually you could write an `HTTPHandler` which will dynamically write the .js file

Comment: Use ajax request from js file to load session variable.

Answer (score 1):

i think try to write your session value to a hidden html element and read value of this hidden element with javascript as follow :

```
<input type="hidden" id="session" value="'<%=Session["username"]%>'">
```

at your js:

```
var sessionValue =document.getElementById("session").value;
```

Comment: This is bad practice. Write that value into a JS variable instead to avoid polluting the DOM and the tree traversing to get the value.

Comment: why it is bad practice can you explain it

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what is your scripting languauge in server side,
if it is JSP or PHP following should work.

```
var sessionValue = "'"+<%=Session["username"]%>+"'"
alert(sessionValue)
```

Comment: Scripting language is `aspx`(Asp.net), already mention in question.