# Get value from included javascript file

Tags: javascript

I am including a javascript file in my web page like as follows,

```
 <script src="my_script.js?mytestvalue" type='text/javascript' ></script>
```

Is possible to take the value `mytestvalue` to a variable in my javascript file `my_script.js` ?

ie

```
 var my_value=somefunction();
 //my_value = 'mytestvalue';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass vars to JavaScript via the SRC attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1017424/851811) or [Passing parameters to JavaScript files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2190801/851811)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343801/pass-variable-to-external-js-file

Comment: it's hard to see any reason to do this. what's that you're really trying to achieve here? why do you want to do this?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath , I am trying to avoid caching that js file in browser,each time this value will be passed dynamically,I need to get that value,and do some execution based on that value

Comment: @Shin: this is a way to avoid caching. but it's unrelated. using this value is an entirely different issue. just use `var config = ....`

Answer (score 1):

You can get all scripts with `document.getElementsByTagName("script")` and loop trough all to find `my_script.js`.

When the right script is found you pick the value from the `src`.

```
window.onload = function() {
   var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script"); //All script
   for(i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
      var script = scripts[i].src; //The src
      if(script.substring(script.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, script.indexOf("?")) == 
              "my_script.js") //If script src is my_script.js
           var my_value = script.substring(script.indexOf("?")+1); //Get my_value
           //Do something with my value
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this to the my_script.js:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    currentScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1],
    searchString = currentScript.src.split('?')[1];
```

The last loaded script (i.e. current running script) is in the last index of `document.getElementsByTagName('script')`, then just extract the search string from the `src`.

Use of this might make sense if you'll create the script tag dynamically. In a case of a hardcoded tag it's simpler to use a global variable.