# Passing key-value pairs to a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

Can you pass key-value pairs to a JavaScript file like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/script.js?key=value"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, answered previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203933/is-there-any-analogue-in-javascript-to-the-file-variable-in-php/1204095#1204095

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily, unless you want them to be processed by server-side code that generates Javascript.

However, you can define variables in an earlier `script` block as parameters.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var key = value;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/script.js></script>
```

You can then use the `key` variable in `script.js` just like any other variable.

**EDIT**: As Upper Stage pointed out, it would be a better idea to put the parameters inside their own namespace.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyScriptParameters = {
        param1: 123,
        param2: "Hello",
        param3: new Date,
        param4: function(text) { ... }
    };
</script>
```

You could then write `MyScriptParameters.param2` in `script.js` (Or in any other script on the page)

Comment: Yes, but perhaps defined in a namespace other than the global.

Comment: the scriptaculous example proves that you can do this just fine, without assigning variables.

Comment: I know that this is possible, but it's not that simple to do.

Answer (score 6):

That technique is used by [scriptaculous](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous) (see [line 54](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/blob/master/src/scriptaculous.js#L54)):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptaculous.js?load=effects,dragdrop">
</script>
```

You can achieve this by inspecting the source of the `script` elements on your page, I leave you a framework independent function:

```
function getScriptVariable(scriptName, key) {
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
      n = scripts.length, scriptSource, i, r;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scriptSource = scripts[i].src;
    if(scriptSource.indexOf(scriptName)>=0) {
      r = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
      var keyValues = r.exec(scriptSource);
      return keyValues[1];
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can embed a script in the way you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js?myKey=myValue">
</script>
```

And use the above function in this way:

```
var value = getScriptVariable('myScript.js', 'myKey'); // "myValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not like that. The above will perform a GET request on the HTTP server with parameters `key=value`. Those won't (normally) impact on the resource `script.js` being returned to you (which is what the above is asking for).

Answer (score 0):

to add to SLaks answer, json encoding the data handles your escaping needs. in php: `json_encode()`