# how to display text from response from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    NurseCounter nc;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["counterid"]);
        int play = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["display"]);
        try
        {
            nc = new NurseCounter(id);
            Response.Write(nc.RenterCounter(play));
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Write("Counter Error Id=" + Request.QueryString["counterid"]);
        }
    }
}
```

When i test in test.htm

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4464/NurseCounter/Default.aspx?counterid=2&display=6"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and , response dont display in test.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO: [Pass vars to JavaScript via the SRC attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017424/pass-vars-to-javascript-via-the-src-attribute)

***Edit**: Updated to accomodate your comment.

If you'd like to display anything returned by a server side-script/page, you'd need to use AJAX. I would recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for that purpose. A simple example of using it after you've included it looks like this:

```
$.get("mypage.aspx", function(data){
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Once you call this on your page, an alert dialogue box will appear with the output of your page contained in "data". Go through [jQuery's tutorial section](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials). Learn it, live it, love it! :)

Comment: i would like to display text from default.aspx not parameter ?

Comment: Updated my answer as per your comment above.