# Passing parameters to JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

Often I will have a JavaScript file that I want to use which requires certain variables be defined in my web page.

So the code is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var obj1 = "somevalue";
</script>
```

But what I want to do is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
     src="file.js?obj1=somevalue&obj2=someothervalue"></script>
```

I tried different methods and the best one yet is to parse the query string like this:

```
var scriptSrc = document.getElementById("myscript").src.toLowerCase();
```

And then search for my values.

I wonder if there is another way to do this without building a function to parse my string.

Do you all know other methods?

Comment: This is a duplicate question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017424/pass-vars-to-javascript-via-the-src-attribute) and in my opinion a misguided design.  It is much simpler to either use your first variable solution (okay), or have the script define a function which is then called with the variables (better).

Comment: I'm looking for an updated solution that takes advantage of the new ECMAScript 6 functionality... if any

Comment: Using any internal script will trigger CSP reports if site is HTTPS and if CSP is fully enabled. The reason given in the CSP doc is that allowing internal elements can make injection easier.

Comment: I use a Script tag in my HTML to include a JavaScript file, and I specify arguments in the src attribute. But on the JavaScript side, window.location doesn't include the arguments. How do I retrieve them?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

I'd recommend not using global variables if possible. Use a namespace and OOP to pass your arguments through to an object.

This code belongs in file.js:

```
var MYLIBRARY = MYLIBRARY || (function(){
    var _args = {}; // private

    return {
        init : function(Args) {
            _args = Args;
            // some other initialising
        },
        helloWorld : function() {
            alert('Hello World! -' + _args[0]);
        }
    };
}());
```

And in your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   MYLIBRARY.init(["somevalue", 1, "controlId"]);
   MYLIBRARY.helloWorld();
</script>
```

Comment: @Naeem - is file.js loaded 100% of the time when MYLIBRARY.init(["somevalue", 1, "controlId"]); gets executed? Maybe we need on document ready to put it?

Comment: It will depend on what you are doing in those functions, if you are wanting to access DOM elements then yes wrapping it in document.ready is the right thing to do. Yes file.js is loaded on which ever pages you require it on 100% of the time.

Comment: very useful, thanks.  I'm just wondering about  a couple of things though: 1) what is the "= MYLIBRARY || (function" stuff doing? 2) it would appear you have created a JS equiv of a "Singleton" object... is this right?  But, correct me if I'm wrong, there could still be problems with concurrency if code called init() on one part of the page... and helloWorld() was immediately called on another, unrelated part of the page... is there no possibly in JS of creating actual self-contained objects, I wonder? hmmm... kind of over my head for the mo

Comment: 1) If MYLIBRARY exists then use it or define a new object. The intent is to create a global namespace, normally I will use sub namespaces so this line helps to avoid re-defining the top level namespace.
2) Yes, it has created a singleton.

Comment: I have made an example of this idea: [http://plnkr.co/edit/iE0Vr7sszfqrrDIsR8Wi?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/iE0Vr7sszfqrrDIsR8Wi?p=preview)

Comment: Worked wonderfully, of course, you can simply pass the parameters to the function itself if it's called once or with different values each time.

Comment: What does this expression mean? `var MYLIBRARY = MYLIBRARY || (function(){}());`? Why should `MYLIBRARY` be set to a boolean value?

Comment: @Alexander, see my comment above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files/2190927?noredirect=1#comment47136074_2190927

Comment: @NaeemSarfraz  Can you suggest a way to make it work for async scripts also ?

Comment: Its not working for multiple times.. when i use init function two times and call a function from the library.. only second call works first one do not work.. how can i use it multiple times on same page ?

Comment: I kept get "function statement requires a name" error message at line "init : function(Args)", what should I do to fix it ?

Comment: I fixed my problem with keep "return {" at same line, thanks for your great sample, it's awesome!

Comment: Wonderful answer. It will be more convenient to use a JavaScript object to be used.

`MYLIBRARY.init({param:"somevalue", value:1, ctrl:"controlId"});`

and use them inside the JS file as

`_args.param`

Comment: I know answer is old but I can see an issue with this approach. If you were trying to implement a Content Security Policy (CSP) this may not be the best option as will require to allow insecure scripts or add a nonce/hash to the inline script to secure it.

Comment: Exactly. This post does not answer the OP’s question at all, it just offers an alternative way to do the things they’re looking for.
Besides, putting a script inline goes against the recommended CSP (something that probably didn’t exist at the time of this answer?)

Answer (score 105):

You can pass parameters with arbitrary attributes. This works in all recent browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-my_var_1="some_val_1" data-my_var_2="some_val_2" src="/js/somefile.js"></script>
```

Inside somefile.js you can get passed variables values this way:

........

```
var this_js_script = $('script[src*=somefile]'); // or better regexp to get the file name..

var my_var_1 = this_js_script.attr('data-my_var_1');   
if (typeof my_var_1 === "undefined" ) {
   var my_var_1 = 'some_default_value';
}
alert(my_var_1); // to view the variable value

var my_var_2 = this_js_script.attr('data-my_var_2');   
if (typeof my_var_2 === "undefined" ) {
   var my_var_2 = 'some_default_value';
}
alert(my_var_2); // to view the variable value
```

...etc...

Comment: Very nice solution, this even works with the async attribute.

Comment: old but for those googling: this is great if you need to work around a CSP (content security policy). We use a lot of scripts wherein we pass strings determined from language resources  and API keys etc. into JS files.

Comment: Note that you can also use `document.currentScript`, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=document-currentscript for compatibility (or use a polyfill)

Comment: The `$(..)` syntax is jquery, do not forget to include it.

Answer (score 81):

Another idea I came across was assigning an `id` to the `<script>` element and passing the arguments as `data-*` attributes.  The resulting `<script>` tag would look something like this:

```
<script id="helper" data-name="helper" src="helper.js"></script>
```

The script could then use the id to programmatically locate itself and parse the arguments.  Given the previous `<script>` tag, the name could be retrieved like this:

```
var name = document.getElementById("helper").getAttribute("data-name");
```

We get `name` = `helper`

Comment: If you don't want to depend on the id attribute, you can also make your `helper.js` script loop through all `script` tags on the page, looking for the one with `scr="helper.js"`, and then extract `data-name`.

Comment: @jvannistelrooy I haven't tried but I believe one should be able to get to the script through jquery and a clever selector like so: `var this_js_script = $('script[src*=somefile]');` (copied from [above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15069289/521554))

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 23):

Check out this URL.  It is working perfectly for the requirement.

http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html

Thanks a lot to the author. For quick reference I pasted the main logic below:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var myScript = scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];

var queryString = myScript.src.replace(/^[^\?]+\??/,'');

var params = parseQuery( queryString );

function parseQuery ( query ) {
  var Params = new Object ();
  if ( ! query ) return Params; // return empty object
  var Pairs = query.split(/[;&]/);
  for ( var i = 0; i < Pairs.length; i++ ) {
    var KeyVal = Pairs[i].split('=');
    if ( ! KeyVal || KeyVal.length != 2 ) continue;
    var key = unescape( KeyVal[0] );
    var val = unescape( KeyVal[1] );
    val = val.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
    Params[key] = val;
  }
  return Params;
}
```

Comment: I liked this solution, but modified it slightly, to use the fragment identifier, so that it doesn't bust caches: var frag = myScript.src.replace(/^[^\#]+\#?/,'');

Comment: Oh, and I found that putting JSON in there works, as long as you urlencode it.

Comment: @user378221 - are you sure this will always get the right file? I mean this assumes that this file is last. What if more script tags is loaded before this executes? I dont know if that is possible, but I assume document does not wait for code execution to finish to load other tags?

Comment: Better to use Use decodeURI() or decodeURIComponent() instead of unescape as that function is deprecated.

Comment: @Darius.V This works for non-async scripts. I prefer using [option 1 with option 5 as a fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22745553/2479481).

Answer (score 19):

You use Global variables :-D.

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var obj1 = "somevalue";
   var obj2 = "someothervalue";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script">
```

The JavaScript code in 'file.js' can access to `obj1` and `obj2` without problem.

**EDIT** Just want to add that if 'file.js' wants to check if `obj1` and `obj2` have even been declared you can use the following function.

```
function IsDefined($Name) {
    return (window[$Name] != undefined);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That will throw an unreferenced error in IE.  The preferred body of that function is `return typeof window[$Name] !== 'undefined';`.  Please note that you would pass that function a string containing the name of the variable.  It is likely easier to simply check if the variable exists in the calling code (this cannot be implemented as a function) via `if (typeof var !== 'undefined')`.

Comment: Yes, but as per my experience with JavaScript, I would use global variables only for module namespaces and expose just as much as what is needed (like init code, some properties), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190927/1016343). It is too easy to get naming conflicts in complex projects ... spending hours of your time and then finding out you have already used the variable somewhere else in the project.

Comment: Really like that way!

Answer (score 13):

Here is a very rushed proof of concept.

I'm sure there are at least 2 places where there can be improvements, and I'm also sure that this would not survive long in the wild. Any feedback to make it more presentable or usable is welcome.

The key is setting an id for your script element. The only catch is that this means you can only call the script once since it looks for that ID to pull the query string. This could be fixed if, instead, the script loops through all query elements to see if any of them point to it, and if so, uses the last instance of such an script element. Anyway, on with the code:

#### Script being called:

```
window.onload = function() {
//Notice that both possible parameters are pre-defined.
//Which is probably not required if using proper object notation
//in query string, or if variable-variables are possible in js.
var header;
var text;

//script gets the src attribute based on ID of page's script element:
var requestURL = document.getElementById("myScript").getAttribute("src");

//next use substring() to get querystring part of src
var queryString = requestURL.substring(requestURL.indexOf("?") + 1, requestURL.length);

//Next split the querystring into array
var params = queryString.split("&");

//Next loop through params
for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
 var name  = params[i].substring(0,params[i].indexOf("="));
 var value = params[i].substring(params[i].indexOf("=") + 1, params[i].length);

    //Test if value is a number. If not, wrap value with quotes:
    if(isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
  params[i] = params[i].replace(value, "'" + value + "'");
 }

    // Finally, use eval to set values of pre-defined variables:
 eval(params[i]);
}

//Output to test that it worked:
document.getElementById("docTitle").innerHTML = header;
document.getElementById("docText").innerHTML = text;
};
```

#### Script called via following page:

```
<script id="myScript" type="text/javascript" 
        src="test.js?header=Test Page&text=This Works"></script>

<h1 id="docTitle"></h1>
<p id="docText"></p>
```

Comment: so eval will actually set the value as global variable... pretty cool.

Comment: eval is evil run away

Comment: @barrychapman - oh man, 2010. I'm surprised there wasn't 10 other red flags in there.

Answer (score 9):

might be very simple

for example

```
<script src="js/myscript.js?id=123"></script>
<script>
    var queryString = $("script[src*='js/myscript.js']").attr('src').split('?')[1];
</script>
```

You can then convert query string into json like below

```
var json = $.parseJSON('{"' 
            + queryString.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"') 
            + '"}');
```

and then can use like

```
console.log(json.id);
```

Answer (score 7):

HTML:

```html
<script src='greet.js' data-param1='hello' data-param2='world'></script>
```

```js
// greet.js:
const prm1=document.currentScript.dataset.param1;
const prm2=document.currentScript.dataset.param2;
```

Comment: wow `document.currentScript`. you learn something new every day. thanks!

Comment: Great solution.  Note that this does not work if the script is loaded as a module.

Answer (score 6):

This can be easily done if you are using some Javascript framework like jQuery. 
Like so,

```
var x = $('script:first').attr('src'); //Fetch the source in the first script tag
var params = x.split('?')[1]; //Get the params
```

Now you can use these params by splitting as your variable parameters.

The same process can be done without any framework but will take some more lines of code.

Comment: There's also a jQuery plugin called parseQuery that makes this even easier: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/parseQuery

Comment: @JimmyCuadra - unfortunately, the link you provided is broken. But I found a similar approach in jQuery itself: **[jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)**

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could have the javascript file being built by any of the scripting languages, injecting your variables into the file on every request. You would have to tell your webserver to not dish out js-files statically (using mod_rewrite would suffice).

Be aware though that you lose any caching of these js-files as they are altered constantly.

Bye.

Comment: Can't understand why this was downvoted. It's a perfectly valid solution resorting to server-side logic. As far as I see, the OP doesn't require it to be a fully-javascript solution.

Comment: @aefxx - You are right. Inside the `<script>` block you can use something like `MyModule.Initialize( '<%: Model.SomeProperty%>',  '<%: Model.SomeOtherProperty%>', ...);` which is rendered on the server. Caution: `<%:` escapes the value, while `<%=` sends the value unescaped. `MyModule` would be a namespace (i.e. a variable inside the .js file which is self-invoked, which exposes the function `Initialize`). I upvoted your answer, because it is a helpful contribution.

Comment: **Note:** The concept, how to create a Module which contains an exposed property is described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190927/1016343) on this page.

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid html (I don't think) but it seems *to work if you create a custom attribute for the script tag in your webpage*:

`<script id="myScript" myCustomAttribute="some value" ....>`

Then access the custom attribute in the javascript:

`var myVar = document.getElementById( "myScript" ).getAttribute( "myCustomAttribute" );`

Not sure if this is better or worse than parsing the script source string.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has been asked a while ago, it is still relevant as of today. This is not a trivial approach using script file params, but I already had some extreme use-cases that this way was most suited.

I came across this post to find out a better solution than I wrote a while ago, with hope to find maybe a native feature or something similar.
I will share my solution, up until a better one will be implemented. This works on most modern browsers, maybe even on older ones, didn't try.

All the solutions above, are based on the fact that it has to be injected with predefined and well marked SCRIPT tag and rely completely on the HTML implementation. But, what if the script is injected dynamically, or even worse, what if you are write a library, that will be used in a variety of websites?
In these and some other cases, all the above answers are not sufficient and even becoming too complicated.

First, let's try to understand what do we need to achieve here. All we need to do is to get the URL of the script itself, from there it's a piece of cake.

There is actually a nice trick to get the script URL from the script itself. One of the functionalities of the native `Error` class, is the ability to provide a stack trace of the "problematic location", including the exact file trace to the last call. In order to achieve this, I will use the stack property of the Error instance, that once created, will give the full stack trace.

Here is how the magic works:

```js
// The pattern to split each row in the stack trace string
const STACK_TRACE_SPLIT_PATTERN = /(?:Error)?\n(?:\s*at\s+)?/;
// For browsers, like Chrome, IE, Edge and more.
const STACK_TRACE_ROW_PATTERN1 = /^.+?\s\((.+?):\d+:\d+\)$/;
// For browsers, like Firefox, Safari, some variants of Chrome and maybe other browsers.
const STACK_TRACE_ROW_PATTERN2 = /^(?:.*?@)?(.*?):\d+(?::\d+)?$/;

const getFileParams = () => {
    const stack = new Error().stack;
    const row = stack.split(STACK_TRACE_SPLIT_PATTERN, 2)[1];
    const [, url] = row.match(STACK_TRACE_ROW_PATTERN1) || row.match(STACK_TRACE_ROW_PATTERN2) || [];
    if (!url) {
        console.warn("Something went wrong. You should debug it and find out why.");
        return;
    }
    try {
        const urlObj = new URL(url);
        return urlObj.searchParams; // This feature doesn't exists in IE, in this case you should use urlObj.search and handle the query parsing by yourself.
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn(`The URL '${url}' is not valid.`);
    }
}
```

Now, in any case of script call, like in the OP case:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js?obj1=somevalue&obj2=someothervalue"></script>
```

In the `file.js` script, you can now do:

```
const params = getFileParams();
console.log(params.get('obj2'));
// Prints: someothervalue
```

This will also work with [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org) and other dynamically injected  file scripts.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me since I am including the script as a module and include it multiple times (each time with different params).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here i have found an another way of doing this same thing. In the reuired js file [*cttricks.js as i have used it for testing, you can have your any .js file*], we'll simply list up all script elements and get the required one as it is always going to be at last index. And then get ".attributes.src.value" from that.

Now, in any case of script call, it is

```
<script src="./cttricks.js?data1=Hello&data2=World"></script>
```

And in the cttricks.js script file,

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var jsFile = new URL("http://" + scripts[scripts.length-1].attributes.src.value);
/*get value from query parameters*/
console.log(jsFile.searchParams.get("data1"));
console.log(jsFile.searchParams.get("data2"));
```

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant really do this by adding variables to the querystring portion of the JS file URL. If its writing the portion of code to parse the string that bothers you, perhaps another way would be to json encode your variables and put them in something like the rel attribute of the  tag? I don't know how valid this is in terms of HTML validation, if thats something you're very worried about. Then you just need to find the rel attribute of the script and then json_decode that.

eg

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='file.js' rel='{"myvar":"somevalue","anothervar":"anothervalue"}'></script>
```

Comment: You can do it with the fake querystring.  It's just not a good idea.  But neither is this.  The rel attribute is meant to specify a type of link relationship, not cram random data into a script tag.

Comment: ^^ agreed. I can't see any problems with just leaving it as is, and using the <script>var obj1="somevalue"</script> approach, its the best way, and I believe - the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question and creative answers but my suggetion is to make your methods paramterized and that should solve all your problems without any tricks.

if you have function:

```
function A()
{
    var val = external_value_from_query_string_or_global_param;
}
```

you can change this to:

```
function B(function_param)
{
    var val = function_param;
}
```

I think this is most natural approach, you don't need to crate extra documentation about 'file parameters' and you receive the same. This specially useful if you allow other developers to use your js file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a way that passes CSP check (which prohibits unsafe-inline) then you have to use nonce method to add a unique value to both the script and the CSP directive or write your values into the html and read them again.

Nonce method for express.js:

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4')

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.nonce = uuidv4()
  next()
})

app.use(csp({
  directives: {
    scriptSrc: [
      "'self'",
      (req, res) => `'nonce-${res.locals.nonce}'`  // 'nonce-614d9122-d5b0-4760-aecf-3a5d17cf0ac9'
    ]
  }
}))

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.end(`<script nonce="${res.locals.nonce}">alert(1 + 1);</script>`)
})
```

or write values to html method. in this case using Jquery:

```
<div id="account" data-email="{{user.email}}"></div>
...


$(document).ready(() => {
    globalThis.EMAIL = $('#account').data('email');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is far more better and modern solution to just use localStorage on the page where the javascript is included and then just re-use it inside the javascript itself. Set it in localStorage with:

```
localStorage.setItem("nameOfVariable", "some text value");
```

and refer to it inside javascript file like:

```
localStorage.getItem("nameOfVariable");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to pass parameters to js modules and read them after via `import.meta.url`.

For example, with the following HTML

```
<script type="module">
import './index.mjs?someURLInfo=5';
</script>
```

the following JavaScript file will log the someURLInfo parameter:

```
// index.mjs
new URL(import.meta.url).searchParams.get('someURLInfo'); // 5
```

The same applies when a file imports another:

```
// index.mjs
import './index2.mjs?someURLInfo=5';

// index2.mjs
new URL(import.meta.url).searchParams.get('someURLInfo'); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document.currentScript.src with a backup of window.location

```
var url = new URL((document.currentScript.src)?document.currentScript.src:window.location.toLocaleString());
var obj1 = url.searchParams.get("obj1");// returns somevalue
```