# how to pass value to a js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-post

I know this question are asked hundreds of times :( but I just want to learn more :).

My question is simple, can I pass a value to a js file like this, if not, how ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/create.js?method=create"></script>
```

Yes, you notice that I have a parameter `method=create` which I want to use in my `create.js`.

I know in jquery ajax, we have an easy way, but you must notice that the ajax method is in included in the js file, how could I pass a parameter to the js file itself ?

Any answer is welcome :) 
Thanks.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, no. What you can do is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var method = "create";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/create.js"></script>
```

Another way is to only define functions inside your javascript file, and then invoke after it has loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/create.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  runMyLoadedCode("create");
</script>
```

Third way is belying my first simplistic answer: access the script tag itself and parse it. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script) how to access the tag that has loaded your script; take its `src` value and cut it up to locate your `method=create`.

Comment: @answered, make it to a global variable :) Thanks. Can I find another way ?

Answer (score 9):

This works perfect for me:

```
<script src="js/script.js" id="myScript" data-url="my_variable"></script>
```

inside the script.js file:

```
var myUrl = document.getElementById("myScript").getAttribute( "data-url" );
```

"myUrl = my_variable" inside the code

you can use myUrl everywhere.

Comment: Super clean and elegant solution, works a treat, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome @brasof
I am glad to hear that