# Pass window.SessionTimeout script to js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, view

I´m doing an MVC app. And this is in my _Layout.cshtml

I need to move it to a a js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.SessionTimeout = (function() {
    var _timeLeft, _popupTimer, _countDownTimer;

    var stopTimers = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(_popupTimer);
        window.clearTimeout(_countDownTimer);
    };

    var updateCountDown = function() {
        var min = Math.floor(_timeLeft / 60);
        var sec = _timeLeft % 60;
        if(sec < 10)
            sec = "0" + sec;

        document.getElementById("CountDownHolder").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;

        if(_timeLeft > 0) {
            _timeLeft--;
            _countDownTimer = window.setTimeout(updateCountDown, 1000);
        } else  {
            document.location = "Home/TimeOutPage";
        }            
    };

    var showPopup = function() {
        _timeLeft = 60;
        updateCountDown();
        ClientTimeoutPopup.Show();
    };

    var schedulePopup = function() {
        stopTimers();
        _popupTimer = window.setTimeout(showPopup, @PopupShowDelay);
    };

    var sendKeepAlive = function() {
        stopTimers();
        ClientTimeoutPopup.Hide();
        SessionTimeout.schedulePopup();
    };

    return {
        schedulePopup: schedulePopup,
        sendKeepAlive: sendKeepAlive
    };

})();
```

I try to copy only the code between the script tag but it doesn't work. I know the problem is with the function signature

**window.SessionTimeout = (function() { ...**

but i don´t know hot to use **window.SessionTimeout** in a js file.

The @PopupShowDelay is define in my view like this:

```
       @functions { 
        public int PopupShowDelay
        {
            get { return 60000 * (Session.Timeout - 1); }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, i found the error.
The problem is the variable

```
@PopupShowDelay
```

I defined that at the *view* and was trying to read the *.js* file.

So, i'm going tho check this:
[Passing parameters to JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files)

Thankls!!

Comment: You can just copy it as is. Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. But i doesn´t work. Don´t know why

Answer (score 0):

You could have problems with `this` context in the nested function.
[You can read more here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/javascript-this-different-contexts/)

Answer (score 0):

your code should be working, if you linked the file in a script tag at the end of your template's document body and the file is being loaded correctly (test with a console.log if your code is executed).