# Show A Popup Warning Before Session Timeout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, session, timeout

I have gone through several article with the caption mentioned as in header, most of them discussed about the implemenation of it in ASP.NET instead of ASP.NET MVC.One of the better article i read was [ASP.NET MVC - How To Show A Popup Warning Before Session Timeout](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2011/07/11/asp-net-mvc-how-to-show-a-popup-warning-before-session-timeout-aspnetmvc.aspx) , but was using third party control

I have some queries about the implementation of session timeout.

1. How can I Implement the above mentioned scenario (using [Jquery Timeout Control](http://rigoneri.github.io/timeout-dialog.js/))??
2. Where should I write the code so that it is accessible everywhere in the page?
3. If an user wishes to stay on the current page, how to perform this scenario  without refreshing the page(refresh means all data is lost if the user is filling a form)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems self explanatory. Anyways, check [this](https://github.com/rigoneri/timeout-dialog.js/blob/master/index.html#LC114) out.

The link above answers your 2nd question.

regarding 3rd, make use of `keep_alive_url` in `timeoutDialog()` constructor.

**Update:-**

If you want to go with jQuery only, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023916/javascript-auto-logout-code#answer-23024313) out.

For a plain js solution, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572938/force-logout-users-if-users-are-inactive-for-a-certain-period-of-time#answer-955704).

Alternatively, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704797/pass-window-sessiontimeout-script-to-js-file) out for the implementation that you started with.

Comment: Can you kindly  explain `second query`. How can I dynamically call the event when session expires..

Comment: As I understand, you can set the timeout session attribute to the required amount of time in the Web.config file. The same amount of time could be set for `countdown` property in `timeoutDialog()`. Generally these session timeout implementation start if there is no activity on page. Is this how things should behave for you as well?

Comment: Yes..also is there an event named `window.sessiontimeout` in javascript.I read about this in the above mentioned tutorial.

Comment: Hi @ksg sorry for late reply... guess what you need is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023916/javascript-auto-logout-code#answer-23024313 check out the explanation of the question and the answer. I feel thats what you need. As a matter of fact I've used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023916/javascript-auto-logout-code#answer-23024313 in my app. Works like a charm. The first link in this comment should do the work for you. have edited my answer.

Comment: One more thing, `window.SessionTimeout` is not an event in native js, it's just a custom function expression that the blogger has provided. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704797/pass-window-sessiontimeout-script-to-js-file too.