# Explain this please: var MYLIBRARY = MYLIBRARY || (function(){

Tags: javascript, encapsulation

I've stumbled upon construct that I'm not sure what it does

```
var MYLIBRARY = MYLIBRARY || (function(){
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190927/680815

I don't have much rep. yet so I can't post a comment to ask about so well, sorry for the mess. :)

Does it mean if MYLIBRARY is defined use it and if not assign encapsulated code?

Thanks,

Comment: This defines MYLIBRARY if it isn't already set. It's not assigning a reference to the function; it's invoking the function and assigning its return value.

Comment: (I'll note that "is set" isn't correct terminology, but hopefully you get the point. This pattern is often used for placing many class-like things in namespaces across many files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it does pretty much what you think.

> if MYLIBRARY is defined it is used, if not it is assigned the encapsulated code?

Answer (score 3):

that checks if MYLIBRARY not undefined, null or false then keep it as it is, else it will be the function assigned.

in another words:

```
if (!MYLIBRARY) {
    MYLIBRARY = function(){};
}
```

but in your snippet I think MYLIBRARY is always undefined because you're setting the variable when you check or it's duplicating.

Comment: Your code example is not equivalent because you removed the `var`, which means that it'll throw if it hadn't been previously declared. And no, `MYLIBRARY` is not always `undefined` unless this code happened to be inside a function. Seems more likely to be global.

Comment: if MYLIBRARY is global then why to re-declare it? you think that is right? whatever, I said: "I think" which means it depends on the code before.

Comment: Well, that's the whole point. If it's global, but it may or may not be defined, then you use the technique in the question. For a local, it doesn't make sense unless it's a function parameter that may or may not have received a value.