# inject <SCRIPT> tag giving it a proper location

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The use case: using a "legacy" PHP file I want to intercept submits and links so that instead of rewriting the entire page they just replace a given DIV's contents.  So I use JQ load to load the PHP file.  But this injected PHP-produced stuff must also contain the JS/JQ code to intercept the future submits and links.  No problem doing this with a single such DIV on the page.

If you want multiple DIVs on a page all doing this, you need the SCRIPTs, when they run (they all run the same 'xxx.js' file), to be able to detect their parent DIV.  The idea is to have, therefore, multiple SCRIPTs, all invoking 'xxx.js', each being incorporated in its reference DIV.

- I've tried incorporating the {SCRIPT src='xxx.js'} tag so that it's produced by the loaded PHP file.
- I've also tried calling the {SCRIPT src='xxx.js'} on successful return from load(), i.e. by using getScript().
- Also on return from load(), I've tried append() to append the string "{SCRIPT src='xxx.js'}{/SCRIPT}" at the end of the DIV of my choice.

The problem is that with an injected SCRIPT like this it always seems to turn out that the parent is HEAD, and that it has no sibling elements: i.e. when you go:

```
var this_js_script = $( document.currentScript );
var script_parent = this_js_script.parent();
```

(NB I have also tried the other techniques listed in the most popular answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script) to try to access the SCRIPT element from "within itself")

It then proves impossible, when the script file is running, to find out where it is, and thus gain a reference to its DIV (which in theory is its parent).

There may be someone who knows what I'm talking about and has a solution! Someone may on the other hand ask me to do a JS Fiddle.  I've never done one and I imagine this would not be the simplest ever.

Comment: could you provide a skeleton of the page, because a certain few things are not really clear. for example when you mention the scripts invoking `xxx.js` do you mean to say that they all call a function inside `xxx.js` which tries to report which div the caller is in? because your problem could be due to the behaviour in the **notes** section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript).

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  Well, technically they are all calling a function in xxx.js, because I tend to think it's good practice to use main() systematically in JS files.  But I think your link does indeed specify the problem.  And yes, I'm trying to find the DIV where the SCRIPT is meant to have been injected.  The simplest multi-DIV "page skeleton" would just be one at the top and one underneath: I'm trying to put one old PHP file's output in the upper DIV and another old PHP file's output in the lower DIV...

Comment: so basically the only part of the code you really have control over in terms of content is the main function right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Hayko Koryun's is a good approach.

In the end I found two ways of re-engineering the problem which avoid the need for the script tags to be in a particular place.

One involves passing params in rather clever way explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files) (answer of Naeem Sarfraz).

But in fact, in the end, what I have done is to design it so that a single script ultimately runs its own main() function after a successful return from a JQ load() intercepting a submit ... so I have avoided the question of where the script tag is in fact located, and favoured the idea of a JQ "framework" which handles everything, rather than "handing off" control to the PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution for you.

What happens is that the functions inside the legacy code call the main function. The main function gets the caller's function body as a string and then looks up all `script` objects on the page trying to see if it can match this string with any of them. If a match is found it highlights the parent `div`.

Note that I don't think this would work if the calling function is anonymous.

```css
.code-block
{
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.johnny
{
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function main(param)
  {
 var script = arguments.callee.caller.toString();

 var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

 for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i)
 {
   if(typeof scripts[i].parentElement != "undefined")
   {
  if(scripts[i].innerText.indexOf(script) != -1)
  {
    scripts[i].parentNode.className = scripts[i].parentNode.className + " johnny";
  }
   }      
 }
  };
</script>
<div class="code-block">
  <script>
 function doSomething(){}
  </script>
</div>
<div class="code-block">
  <script>
 function doSomethingElse(){}
  </script>
</div>
<div class="code-block">
  <script>
 function doSomethingRandom(){}
  </script>
</div>
<div class="code-block">
  <script>
 function heresJohnny(){main("");}
  </script>
</div>
<script>
  heresJohnny();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for this... I think it might not work if injected: I think you'd find that the SCRIPT tags in the injected script would have HEAD as their parent, not the DIV one would expect.  In the end I have re-engineered things to have an all-enveloping JQ management "framework", as explained in my answer.