# Use Symfony2 route in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I have a Symfony app using a little bit of Javascript. There is a ajax request calling an API in Symfony:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://symfony.dev/api/price",
    cache: false,
    data: {
        'volume': $('#tunnel_step_one_volume').val(),
        'delivery': $('#tunnel_step_one_isStandardDelivery').val()
    },

    success: function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        Command.refreshData(data);
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
})
```

Now the URL is hard coded.

My question is:

**What is the best practices to give the JS file my route name in Symfony?**

Comment: if you use twig, you can pass a variable to the template and use the variable in the js included.

Comment: check this option: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2190927/2209876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle to achieve this.

The easiest way would be to return the route from the controller and print in a js variable inside your page:

```
<script> myUrl = {{myUrl}} </script>
```

But i wouldn't consider it best practice.

Comment: Your easy way is a bad practice. The bundle is a nice practice