# Possible to get query parameters of the <script> src JavaScript URL?

Tags: javascript, html5-history, query-string, script-tag, location-href

As an example, I have the following html:

```
<body>
  <script src="code.js?q=xyz"></script>
</body>
```

I want to be able to read the `q=xyz` query parameter from within `code.js`. I tried:

```
console.log(window.location.href)
```

But it gives me the html document's URL, not `code.js`'s URL (I could then parse the URL for the query parameters).

Is there any way to get an imported JavaScript file's query parameters from within that JavaScript? I know I could read the query parameters on a server and then send back JavaScript that has the query parameters embedded, but I don't want that. I want to be able to put JavaScript files on CDNs that can be configured via query parameters.

Comment: you want `document.currentScript`

Comment: Before you do that, you should check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `document.currentScript.src` to access the `<script>`'s `src`-attribute and then extract the query parameter. For older browsers (such as IE 11) access the `src`-attribute by:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var src = scripts[scripts.length - 1].src;
```

This will return the `src`-attribute of the last executed script.
In some cases the last executed script is not the current script (for example, if a script manipulates other `<script>`-elements), and therefore it's a bit unreliable.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping existed! Thanks. Unfortunately IE 11 doesn't support `document.currentScript`: http://caniuse.com/#search=currentScript

I normally wouldn't care about IE 11, but in this particular case I have to care... The only polyfill I found works on IE 6-10 and expressly doesn't work on IE 11 :( https://github.com/JamesMGreene/document.currentScript

Any workaround for IE 11?

Comment: There's a workaround. I'll add it to the answer. I think this has been answered somewhere else on SO, tho - I can't locate the question.

Comment: I could search all `<script>` tags and look for one with my URL... Then get the query parameters.