# Laravel pass value to javascript

Tags: laravel

Im learning laravel. I wanna ask a stupid question. Hope be helped from all of you.

When a controller return a view, I can send value blade template.

```
return view('home', ['message' => 'this is home page']);
```

I can get that from home.blade.php as:

```
<h1>{{$message}}</h1>
```

I can even send that value to javascript by the way below:

```
var message = "{{$message}}";
```

Yeah, that it!

**But how can i send that value to separate javascript file.**

/resources/views/home.blade.html:

```
<script src="/js/home.js"></script>
```

how can i get that value to /public/js/home.js if i dont use the way below?

```
<script>var message = {{$message}}</script>
<script src="/js/home.js"></script>
```

Thank for reading!

Comment: You can do that easily using the `querySelector`

Comment: Why don't you pass an encoded value to your blade file and get that within a variable and access it as an object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a script tag contain all your dynamic values, and make your file

> /js/home.js

use it

like this

```
<script>
   var appSettings = {message :"{{$message}}"};
</script>
<script src="/js/home.js"></script>
```

so inside home.js
you can access this value

```
alert(appSettings.message);
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought about that, but i wanna send many values, i think it make javascript code in blade file be long. So i hope a another way :D

Comment: You can check these solutions:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2190927/292927