# Better way to pass parameters to JS file

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

Which is the better way to pass parameters to external JS file?

Method 1: Simple querystring parameters

```
<script src="https://somedomain.com/somejsfile.js?param1&param2"></script>
```

Method 2:through object

```
<script src="https://somedomain.com/somejsfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">someJSObj.init(["param1&param2"]);</script>
```

Comment: what about about passing values via localstorage? Is there any flaws of using localstorage or cache

Comment: passed parameters will be different every time and depending on that some div structure is created.

Comment: Okay, I've used window variable for this. `window.myVar  = 0`

Comment: I read this on stackoverflow itself, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190927/1747014. Just want to find the better approach.

Comment: http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html

Comment: This is good but my question remains is that, does passing variables to Js file like in method 2 has any advantage over passing as normal querystring?

Answer (score 0):

You can define global vars before the script files and then directly access them to the script file as given below,

/* =========== index.html =========== */

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
    var global = {
        key: 'value'
    };    
    </script>

    <script src="script.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

/* =========== index.html =========== */

/* =========== script.js =========== */

```
console.log(global.key);
```

/* =========== script.js =========== */

Comment: How good is this in case of passing multiple and long parameters i.e. parameters with some text with special characters?