# Run script in react with optional variables

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to run a script in react and need to include variables to the script. I use this script-reader: https://louisrli.github.io/blog/2020/06/04/react-dynamic-script-hook/#.YKvsrOtCRB0 . It works fine without variables but I don't know where I can include the variables properly. This is how it works with javascript:

```
<script>
    var option = {
        style: "something"
    }
</script>
<script async src="sourcescript"></script>
```

Do you have an idea how I could include this option var?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters to JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files)

Comment: I don't think that your answer provides a solution to my question because I use react to make my script work and I don't know at which point and how I can include the variables. I think this is completely different...