# In Javascript, is it possible to pass a variable into <script> "src" parameter?

Tags: external, javascript

Is it possible in Javascript to pass a variable through the `src` parameter? ie.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/twitter.js?handle=aplusk" />`
```

I'd like `twitter.js` to look and see if a "handle" was passed before doing what I need it to do and returning its response back to the originating page calling `twitter.js`.

I had originally created a function in `twitter.js` that did the following:

```
function getHandle() {
  var vars = [], hash, username;
  var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

  for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    if (hash[0] == 'handle') 
     username = hash[1];
  }

  return username;
}
```

The problem, and it makes sense, is that window.location.href is not going to work on a file that I'm calling from `<script src="" />`

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that `window.location.href` is not going to work because when the script runs in the page (whether it's *external* through a src or *inline* javascript), it will run in the scope of the document which exposes that variable.

Comment: window.location never refers to the url of the script. It refers to the url hosting the script

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass vars to JavaScript via the SRC attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017424/pass-vars-to-javascript-via-the-src-attribute)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see two solutions here.

First: you can process those GET parameters on the server where the twitter.js is hosted, so that it will dynamically change the js file. For example, you file is:

```
var handle = {{ handle }};
```

And your server somehow processes the file, replacing that twitter.js template file dependent on what request was sent.

The second option would be to set the global variables on the page where twitter.js is loaded, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.twitter_js_handle = 'aplusk';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/twitter.js" />
```

And in twitter.js:

```
var handle = window.twitter_js_handle || null;
```

Answer (score 7):

I use the following pattern to convert query variables from `<script src="script.js?foo=bar&baz=zing"></script>` to an object containing key:value pairs. Code is placed at the top of script.js:

```js
    var getVars = {};
    
    (function(){
        var scripts, currentScript, queryString;

        scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        currentScript = scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];
        queryString = currentScript.getAttribute('src').split("?").pop().split('&');
        for(var i=0;i<queryString.length;i++){
            var keyVal = queryString[i].split('=');
            getVars[ keyVal[0] ] = keyVal[1];
        }
    
    }());
    // console.info( getVars );
    // Object { foo="bar", baz="zing"}
```

This probably won't work with deferred / asynchronously added script elements, as it relies on immediate code execution.

Comment: The code was broken (one of the `keyVal`s was missing a Y) so I've submitted a fix. But also the `console.log` actually contains a question mark (`Object { ?foo="bar", baz="zing"}`). So I've borrowed from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816530/4829915) and submitted an edit to change `replace(/[^\?]*/,'')` to `split("?").pop()`, which I assume is also quicker.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. But the only way you can access that parameter though is through server-side. So, make twitter.js a PHP page (using mod_rewrite or whatever) that grabs `$_GET['handle']` and then serves itself as `Content-Type: text/javascript` and just dump the contents of the js.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use more **safe** approach - must add an ID:

```
<script id="myTargetScript" src="http://example.com/file.js?param=value" />
```

then in your `.js` file

```js
    function GetParams(target_id)
    {
        var getVars = {};
        if( document.getElementById(target_id) )
        {
            var queryString = document.getElementById(target_id).getAttribute('src').split("?").pop().split("&");
            for(var i=0;i<queryString.length;i++){
                var keyVal = queryString[i].split('=');
                getVars[ keyVal[0] ] = keyVal[1];
            }
        }
        return getVars;
    }
        
        
    // console.log(   GetParams('myTargetScript')   );
```