# How get script by pass pamater in script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In html page, I'm include js

```
<script src="/script/lib.js?file=bootstrap,jquery"></script>
```

And in lib.js, I can include like this:

```
if(file=="jquery"){
   $.getScript("//cdn.optimizely.com/js/jquery.js");
}
if(file=="ecomotion"){
  $.getScript("//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.3.0/lib/js/emojione.min.js");
}
if(file=="bootstrap"){
   $.getScript("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js");
}
ect
```

How can we do that?

Comment: You can't pass parameters to scripts, like that.

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to include a JS file that then looks at the GET parameters of that and conditionally includes other scripts? So your question is really how to read the GET parameters of a JS file included using a `script` tag?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Dangit, I was just about to answer with an alternative _*sadface*_

Comment: Feel free to re-open if you have a working solution that's missing in the other question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493319/in-javascript-is-it-possible-to-pass-a-variable-into-script-src-parameter/4494258#4494258

Comment: @Kevin Nagurski yes, that right

Comment: @Juhana: No, that's not the same, that's query string values in the ___page___'s url, not in the JS file's src. Guys, query stings are ___not___ the way to pass variables to JS files. Don't suggest hacks to make it work. Suggest a decent alternative instead.

Comment: One thing to remember is that you're using `$.getScript` which is a jQuery function, so you'll need to get jQuery on the page regardless to make `lib.js` work at all.

Comment: @Juhana This is not my mine, so this is not duplicate, please read again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass parameters to JavaScript files, like that.

You *could*, however, do this:

```
<script>
    window.file = ['bootstrap', 'jquery'];
</script>
<script src="/script/lib.js"></script>
```

In your script:

```
if(window.file.indexOf("bootstrap") !== -1){
// Same for the other file types.
```

The disadvantage here is that you're creating a global variable, which is arguably a bad idea.

The advantage is that you can easily specify a list of files to include, while working around the fact that it's impossible to pass query strings to a JS file.

Comment: Do you any idea not to create a global variable?

Comment: I can't think of anything without a global var, to transfer that variable to the file.

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1**

The only way that you can really do this like you have written is if `lib.js` was interpreted on the server side. For instance in PHP (or Node, or .Net) you could then read the GET and spit out the appropriate `$.getScript` blocks as output.

Pros are that it'll work without any weird hacks. You could even work to make the file cache-able.

A simple `.htaccess` mod-rewrite can direct calls to `libs.js` to a PHP script.

**OPTION 2**

Another option would be to expose a function from `libs.js` that would initialise the includes:

*libs.js*

```
function getMyScripts(scripts){
    /* loop through the `scripts` array and spit out
       the `$.getScript` calls */
}
```

You page would then do this:

```
<script src="libs.js"></script>
<script>
    getMyScripts(['lib1', 'lib2']);
</script>
```

Comment: But if it's processed server-side, what would be the point in using `$.getScript`? Just serve the requested scripts instead.

Comment: @Cerbrus true, but he's loading the scripts from a public CDN, not from his own application, so the point would be to kick things off.