# Get query data in javascript from src attribute

Tags: javascript

Often, when I update a JavaScript or CSS file used by a webpage, I will tack on `v=<version>`. This helps me track what changes I have made but also forces the browser to get the newest version instead of using cache. Example:

```
<script src="functions.js?v=1.4"></script>
```

Is is possible, using JavaScript, to detect any query parameters used? Meaning, could `function.js` detect that `v` is `1.4`?

Comment: Well you could parse the version out of the href

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992354/can-you-pass-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-file
Look at this page to get the answer.

Comment: It's duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976651/javascript-how-do-i-get-the-url-of-script-being-called

Comment: @EAndreyF, not exactly. If the question is about can the script get its own query params, it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no a specific method for this, but you can inspect the DOM as usual:

```
var script = document.querySelector('script[src~="function.js"]');
script.src.replace(/.+?v=/, ''); // that's your version
```

Comment: And then you'll need to apply some helper to get query parameter value you'd like

Comment: Think this can be approved as the right one. Also it should be tested, whether it could be done from the same script. I think you need a separate one.

Comment: `document.querySelector('script[src~="function.js"]')` seems to return null for me, although, for the time being, I was able to loop over `document.querySelectorAll('script')` to manually find my file

Comment: @steveo225 Try `src~="functions.js"` (with `s`) instead of `src~="function.js"`.

Comment: I did make sure the filename was correct. In actuality, the file isn't even named `functions.js`, that was just an example. Not sure why it reports `null`, but like I said, I brute forced it with `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script id="file-js" src="functions.js?v=1.4"></script>
```

Code to find all parameters :

```
var url = document.getElementById('file-js').src;
url = url.replace(/^.*?\?/, '');
var params = url.split('&');
for(var i in params) {
    var pair = params[i].split('=');
    console.log(pair);
}
```