# Use ScriptInjector in GWT with parameters / data attributes

Tags: javascript, gwt

How would you pass id=someScript and param1=value1 to the GWT ScriptInjector?  Ie, the JS:

```
<script src="https://blah.com/someScript.js" id="someScript" param1="value1"></script>
```

Could be loaded like this:

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl("https://blah.com/someScript.js").setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
    }
    public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
    }
}).inject();
```

However, where can I pass in the id="someScript" and param1="value1"?

Comment: I think they are called data attributes:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21253793/418057

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameters in via the URL as you normally would pass parameters in a URL.

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl("https://blah.com/someScript.js?param1="+value1).setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
    }
    public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
    }
}).inject();
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work.

Also, testing this approach, doing this:

<script src="https://blah.com/someScript.js?id=someScript&param1=value1></script>

didn't work either.