# How can i use script parameters into my js file?

Tags: javascript

I have this script code:

```
<script src="http://example.com/embed.js?q=123&parameter1=450&parameter2=300"></script>
```

How can i get the values of q(123)and parameter1(450) and parameter2(300) and use them into embed.js file? I want to make conditions into my embed.js by using these values. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to JavaScript files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to a Script tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292372/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-script-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the script element and ID attribute like this:

```
<script id="embed-script" src="http://example.com/embed.js?q=123&parameter1=450&parameter2=300"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
var url = document.getElementById('embed-script');

function parseGet(val) {
var result = "",
    tmp = [];
var items = url.src.split("?")[1].split('&');

for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    tmp = items[index].split("=");
    if (tmp[0] === val)
        result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
}

return result;
}
```

Get the values like this, in embed.js:

var value1 = parseGet('q');

value1 should then be "123".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't,but you can declare all param before required your js file same as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var q = 123;
    var parameter1 = 450;
    var parameter2 = 300;
  </script>
  <script src="http://example.com/embed.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place the parameters in attributes of the `<script>` tag.

```
<script src="http://example.com/embed.js" q="123" parameter1="450" parameter2="300"></script>
```

You can access these parameters in `embed.js` with

```
document.currentScript.getAttribute('q');
document.currentScript.getAttribute('parameter1');
document.currentScript.getAttribute('parameter2');
```

Note: `document.currentScript`does not work on IE.

For more info [check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript).

Answer (score 0):

You can access `script` tag as the last script tag if ask for it without waiting for document load.

```
~function() {
  var s = document.querySelectorAll("script");
  s = s[s.length-1];
  console.log(s.src);
}();
```