# jQuery get query string from it's own (self) link

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, query-string

Is it possible to have a javascript link like this (notice the query string):

```
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "/js/myScipt.js?v=3"></script>
```

and then in myScript.js get the value of v using jQuery? A javascript answer is okay too, but jQuery is preferred.  Thanks in advance!  I searched all over and all I could find were questions pertaining to getting the value of a query string in the URL, but not from it's own link.

Comment: What is expected result of including `?v=3` at `src` of `<script>` element? _"and then in myScript.js get the value of v using jQuery?"_ What does `myScript.js` do with `?v=3`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292372/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-script-tag

Comment: Perhaps it uses the value of v in some conditional statement, which produced a different affect depending on what v is.  This would be easier than someone editing myScript.js every time to hard code whatever the value of v should be.

Comment: @natel thank you, that link was very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//to set script do some thing like this
var version = 3;
document.write('<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/js/myScipt.js?v='+version+'"></script>');
//or 
$("body").append('<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/js/myScipt.js?v='+version+'"></script>');


//to get v from myscript.js
var getV = document.currentScript.src.split("?v=")[1];
// var getV =  $('script').last().attr("src").split("?v=")[1];
```

Comment: Makes sense, but why would you set the script that way instead of just inserting the link directly as in my example in the original post?

Comment: No reasons just examples

Comment: I thought you were going to say it was a security thing

Comment: Actually no reasons may be you need to make src dynamic, thats all

Comment: Ah, got it. Makes sense, but in my case there's no need to do that. I was thinking more along the lines of using the script on multiple sites, but don't want it to do quite the same thing on every site . I would rather just pass the script a query string than set the value in each copy of the script on each site, and have 10 different version of the script around..  I marked your answer correct because it was the easiest for me to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for you to pass information through the link when calling a script. That JavaScript will run after it has been called. There is for sure a better way to do what you are trying to acomplish with this.

Something like this might give you an idea.

```
 var value;
$("script").each(function(){

var temp = "v=";
If(this.src.indexOf(temp) > -1 )) > -1){

get last digits before "&" if any exist.
And after the index of temp var.
}
});
```

Comment: A bit confused - so how would you get the value of the query string and assign it to a variable?

Comment: Just parse it using the split function. So this.src.split("?v=")[1];

Comment: you mean that `this.src.indexOf(temp) > -1` not `(temp.indexOf(this.src)) > -1`