# Security risks of getting query string from <script> link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, hyperlink, query-string

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252285/jquery-get-query-string-from-its-own-self-link/40252409), I asked if it was possible to do this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/js/myScipt.js?v=3"></script>
```

and then get the value of v within myScipt.js using jQuery or JavaScript.  Apparently, yes it can be done like so:

```
var getV = document.currentScript.src.split("?v=")[1];      // JS
var getV =  $('script').last().attr("src").split("?v=")[1]; // jQuery
```

My new question - Am I creating any kind of security risk that can be exploited by doing this? If so, is there a way to sanitize the value of the queryString to eliminate the risk?

In case it matters, myScript.js uses jQuery to insert some HTML it constructs (some divs and an image) based on some conditionals into the page.

Comment: Is the script tag put in the dom by your code or some third party stuff?

Comment: The script tag is put in the DOM by myself just before the closing body tag.  It is my own script and doesn't use AJAX or otherwise have any interaction with the server.

Comment: Now you have a user-submitted string in a variable. No security issue in itself. It's what you go on to do with that variable that counts. If you execute it as JavaScript using `eval()` then clearly you've got a cross-site-script problem. If you write it into HTML markup (eg with `innerHTML`, `$el.html()` or `document.write()`) then you've got an HTML-injection problem also leading to cross-site-scripting. If you construct HTML safely using DOM text and attribute properties then you're fine.

Comment: @bobince - Thank you for the answer.  I think I am OK as I am constructing the HTML safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, security is not the word I would use to refer to javascript stuff. All client code is browsable, editable, exploitable. It doesn't really matter what you do in javascript as long as your server code is assuming user input can be forged/corrupted. All javascritp frameworks put a lot of logic in the browser and thus allowing the user to mess with it, and that doesnt mean those frameworks are bad, furthermore request can also be forged, so, short answer is ... security holes are not in your client, but in your server. Your client is "a big hole" by definition and all that comes from it must be treated as dangerous.

What you must ask yourself is: "can the user request/push something from/to the server that will produce an unwanted execution" ? You can let the client-user ask to format your hard drive or retrieve all your user's passwords. Expect that to happen. But... will your server allow it?

Comment: My script doesn't interact with the server at all, i.e. there are no AJAX requests.  It's basically just creates some HTML markup and inserts it into the document.  The query string question came up because depending on the value of the query string, the script would use different class names. That being the case, does it sound possible for something malicious to be pushed to the server?   I'll be using the script on multiple sites so I figured it's easier to use a query string rather than have a different version of myScipt.js on each site with just a single variable changed in the code.

Comment: Having a querystring for serving different script versions doesnt seem sangerous at all. I dont know what your server code does, but if it only reads the value and returns the script you should be fine. Notice users might be able to manually try other querystrings to get the other versions

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The query string will basically just change the HTML that I construct with jQuery.  For example, "myScript.js?v=full" might use a Bootstrap ".container-fluid" class while "myScript.js?v=container" might use the ."container" class instead.  The query string would depend on the layout of the site that I'm using it on.  That's a simple example, but it basically describes what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I see. Security concerns regarding javascript come in many flavours. I think the topmost concerns have to do with
1. Using eval() for stuff that is in some way loaded from user input
2. javascript driven ui's in which the user might be able to alter the program's execution in a way that he/she will be able to trick the server into executing or getting protected code/data. This is not the issue in your case

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and sorry for missing it earlier.  That all makes sense to me and I feel better about doing it and not creating a security risk.  Thanks again!