# appendChild where javascript is included

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to create a JavaScript element where the script is included.

Example:

```
<script src='addDiv.js'></script>
```

The addDiv.js simply adds a customized div as below:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.setAttribute("id", "myspecialdiv");
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

I want to add this div wherever this script is included instead of at the end of body. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: just target the script tag by src content or give it a `id` and insert there

Comment: You could pass params from the script tag to the script code, for example an id and in this way add the div just next to script tag. Read SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292372/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-script-tag

Comment: How can I do that ? How can I refer the script tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most modern browsers you can use [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript);

```html
<script>
  function replaceScript(el, text) {
    let p = document.createElement('p')
    p.innerText = text;    
    el.replaceWith(p);
  }
</script>

<script>  
  replaceScript(document.currentScript, 'Test 1');
</script>

<script>  
  replaceScript(document.currentScript, 'Test 2');
</script>
```

Comment: But this means I will have to include at least two scripts, one to add replaceScript functions, and another to call that function. Is there a way to do this by just one ?

Comment: Can just as easily be done in one. I only did it this way to show it working