# User specified api key in React built app

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build an app (which is basically a widget) so a user can embed it into their website. The issue I'm having is there needs to be a unique api key for each user to show their pertinent data. Does anyone know what the best way for me is so a user can define their api key themselves and pass that to the "main.XXXXX.chunk.js" file? Thank you in advance!

Comment: why don't you save the api key in table and get it via api?

Comment: How do you expect a user / developer to use this widget? through React.render or by something like an iframe?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't create the api and defining the key in the code is the only way for me to get the data I need.

Comment: @TauseefAhmad like it was explained on this site...https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-embed-a-react-application-on-any-website-1bee1d15617f

Comment: In that case you can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32589923