# Pass a variable to Javascript directly from <script> HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to pass a variable directly from the HTML tag `<script>`:

```
<script async src="https://example.com/lib.js" site="test.com"></script>
```

such that `lib.js` can access `site` like a regular variable?

Comment: This is not a commonly used pattern. You should probably just allow people to invoke some setup method and pass in actual JavaScript variables.

Comment: @meagar Yes, I see it's not commonly used. If you want, could you elaborate on why it's not often used, and why invoking a setup is a superior solution, in an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameters to a Script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292372/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-script-tag)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<script async src="https://example.com/lib.js" site="sitePath"></script>
```

and:

```
site = document.currentScript.getAttribute('site'); // sitePath
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes this is possible. Instead of creating a `site` attribute we can use the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset). This is made for custom (data-)attributes.

All you need to do now is give the script an ID and query your data.

HTML:

```
<script async src="script.js" data-site="test.com" id="myscript"></script>
```

JS:

```
const script = document.querySelector("#myscript");

console.log(script.dataset.site);
```

**EDIT: without a querySelector**

```
console.log(document.currentScript.dataset.site);
```

Comment: Interesting solution! I'm being nitpicky: do you think there's a way *without* asking people using my lib to set an ID to the `<script>`?

Comment: @Basj [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)

Answer (score 0):

```
let me = document.querySelector('script[src$="lib.js"]');
me.getAttribute("site");
```

In addition to the answers above, this script will let you have more freedom to change the script's file name or path

Comment: This is a very broad selector which could return multiple matches.