# read parameter on js file

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass vars to JavaScript via the SRC attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017424/pass-vars-to-javascript-via-the-src-attribute)

May I know how to read get the **p** value on js file link like filename.js?p=value with local javascript in the js file? Any function to work like the $_GET['p'] in php? Thanks.

Comment: Its possible. Check [This](http://www.dominopower.com/issues/issue200004/howto002) out

Comment: This just tells you (in a very convoluted manner) how to use `window.location.search` to extract the query string from the current request url. But that is completely different than a query string *to* a javascript file.

Comment: @BenLee it is a completely different question. One is pass by variable, this is pass by link's parameter. Pls read the question again Ben. Thanks.

Comment: @davidlee Look again at the non-accepted answers to that question: they show how to get query parameters from the URL used to load the script.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
var tmp = location.href, it;
if (q) it = tmp.substr(q + 1).split('&');
else it = '';
for (var i in it) {
    var t = it[i].split('=');
    if (t[0] == 'p') {
        //do something
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is wrong with this one?

Comment: Not the one to downvote, but let me explain what is wrong: `window.location` point to the location of the document that *loaded* the current script. OP wants to extract the query string of the script file *itself* (as loaded from the HTML document).

Answer (score -1):

```
function _GET( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

This will do the equivalent in javascript.