# Pass parameter to GWT nocache.js from external web portal

Tags: javascript, gwt, methods, native

I have created a `GWT` widget with root container ID "widgetContainer" and the corresponding compiled file is gwtwidget.nocache.js. I have created a war file of this widget and hosted in a local server localhost:8888/gwtwidget.

I created another jsp application and the index.jsp is as follow: (Integrated `GWT` module into `JSP` application)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://localhost:8888/gwtwidget/gwtwidget/gwtwidget.nocache.js?appId=461333815262909&appId=461333815262909&appId=461333815262909&appId=461333815262909"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="widgetContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to retrieve the parameters which are passed through the nocache.js file from the `JSP` application. For this purpose, I'm using the code

```
public static native String getParameter( String moduleName, String parameterName ) /*-{
var search = "/" + moduleName + ".nocache.js";
var scripts = $doc.getElementsByTagName( "script" );
for( var i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i ) {
    if( scripts[ i ].src != null && scripts[ i ].src.indexOf( search ) != -1 ) {
        var parameters = scripts[ i ].src.match(/\w+=\w+/g);
        for( var j = 0; j < parameters.length; ++j ) {
            var keyvalue = parameters[ j ].split( "=" );
            if( keyvalue.length == 2 && keyvalue[ 0 ] == parameterName ) {
                return unescape( keyvalue[ 1 ] );
            }
        }
    } 
}
return null;
}-*/;
```

But unable to get the parameter values into the `GWT` widget. Can any one please help me in solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want pass parameters using query string, it is not straight forward. There are ways to that. You can refer the following posts:

1. [Passing parameters to JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files)
2. [Pass vars to JavaScript via the SRC attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017424/pass-vars-to-javascript-via-the-src-attribute)

There is another way, which I feel is simpler. You can set a cookie in your jsp file. You can read the cookie in your GWT module.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie="appId=461333815262909"
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://localhost:8888/gwtwidget/gwtwidget/gwtwidget.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="widgetContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can access the cookie 'appId' in your GWT module as:

```
String param = Cookies.getCookie("appId");
```